# How to display data in view of the CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Unable to display the data in a CodeIgniter view. Need to print the *builders_name* in a CodeIgniter view. So far I have the following code:

**Model :**

```
public function get_builders()  
  {  
    $query1 = $this->db->select('name')->from('builders')->where("name LIKE 'a%'")->limit(3)->get();
    $query2 = $this->db->select('name')->from('builders')->where("name LIKE 'b%'")->limit(3)->get();
    $result1 = $query1->result();
    $result2 = $query2->result();

    return array($result1, $result2); 
  }
```

**Controller:**

```
public function index(){       
            $this->load->database();   
            $data['h']= $this->Builders_Model->get_builders(); 
            $this->load->view('home', $data);
}
```

**View:**

```
<?php  foreach ($h->result as $row) { ?>
    <tr> 
        <td><a href="#"><?php echo $row->name;?></td></a>  
     </tr>  
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: is it returning the exact data you want to display?

Answer (score 1):

Don't like this try it

```
public function get_builders()  
{  
$query1 = $this->db->select('name')
                   ->from('builders')
                   ->like('name','a')
                   ->or_like('name','b')
                   ->limit(3)->get();

$result = $query1->result();


return $result;
}
```

views code

```
 <?php  foreach ($h as $row) { ?>
     <tr> 
       <td><a href="#"><?php echo $row->name;?></td></a>  
     </tr>  
<?php } ?>
```

Hope fully works . Thank You

Answer (score 0):

What you pass to the view in Codeigniter is accessible by its name. Just `<php echo $h; ?>` and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use :
<?php
 foreach($h as $row){?>
   <tr> 
   <td><a href="#"><?php echo $row->name;?></td></a>  
 </tr>  
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $h variable in foreach for notation :

```
  <?php
       <tr> 
       <td><a href="#"><?php echo $rowDetail->name; ?></td></a>  
     </tr>  
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First this is you haven't loaded the Builder_modal in your controller try to do some thing like

`$this->load->model('Builder_model');`

after `$this->load->database()`;

Next thing in your view you have to echo like
`echo $h;` or `var_dump($h)` if you have an array

Answer (score 0):

It's really working
model

```
    public function get_builders()  
      {  
        $this->db->select('name'); 
        $this->db->from('builders');
        $this->db->like('name','a');
        $this->db->or_like('name','b');
        $this->db->limit(3);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
      }
```

controller

```
public function index(){       
            $this->load->model('Builder_model');
            $data= $this->Builders_Model->get_builders(); 
            $this->load->view('home', ['data'=>$data]);
}
```

view

```
<?php  foreach ($h->result as $row) { ?>
    <tr> 
        <td><a href="#"><?php echo $row->name;?></td></a>  
     </tr>  
<?php } ?>
```